# Visual Studio 2017 plus yarn?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017, yarnpkg

I am running Visual Studio 2017 on Win10.  I am creating a C# .Net web app.  I decided to try using npm / bower for package management only to discover that I am way behind the times and that yarn is now all the rage -- unless it has also been superseded by now.

I installed node, yarn and a VS package installer that is aware of bower, yarn and other things.  I used the package installer to add several things but quickly found that some of the js libs I commonly use are not in the npm/yarn repo, as far as I can tell.

I download one of these non-repo'd libs and found out how to get yarn to recognize it.

I get to a point when I want to try building my app and wowzers!  There are over 800 new build errors mostly talking about things of the form:

```
    tsc : error TS6053: Build:File node_modules/tsd/build/api.d.ts not found
```

I realized that something wanted `typescript` and `typings` and installed those.  in VS I kept finding new files/folders that had to be added to the project at every step.

I used yarn to "remove" the default `tsd` folder and re-added it.  I used `tsd install` to create the missing config and d.ts files.

I tried to build again and the error count has hit almost 10000.  I took a serious look in the `node_modules` folder and there seem to be a HUGE number of modules that have to be dependencies because I didn't add them.  If there is cruft in there, is there a way to clean it up?

Basically it feels like I am on the doorstep of dependency hell.

Is there yet another layer of package management tech that I am missing that can tame yarn?

Was I a fool to walk down this path?

Should I do something different?  Should I go back to nuget?